# Why Text decoration and navbar are not working?

Tags: html, css, navbar, text-decorations

I'm making a webpage but have problems with Navar and links. My Navar items are not staying in the navar, but just floating down. Also, `text-decoration: none;` is not working and my links are underlined and with a dot at the front.

```css
.navbar {
  background: black;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo"> COLOR</a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nabar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="nabvar__links" id="hope-page">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="nabvar__links" id="about-page">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="nabvar__links" id="services-page">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">SIGN UP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried `border-bottom: none` and `list-style-type: none;` didn't work.
And for navbar, I tried `flex-direction: row`, also didn't work.

Comment: `nabvar` != `navbar` - Closing for reason typo.

Answer (score -2):

`navbar__links`  `navbar__menu` these two class name in HTML is incorrectly spelled

```css
.navbar {
  background: black;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo"> COLOR</a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="hope-page">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">SIGN UP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -3):

You should check your class names and your selectors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYmSe.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).